# Find cardinality of set

Tags: algorithm

I have faced the following problem recently:

We have a sequence A of M consecutive integers, beginning at A[1] = 1:
1,2,...M (example: M = 8 , A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 )

We have the set T consisting of all possible subsequences made from L_T consecutive terms of A. 
(example L_T = 3 , subsequences are {1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5},...). Let's call the elements of T "tiles".

We have the set S consisting of all possible subsequences of A that have length L_S. ( example L_S = 4, subsequences like {1,2,3,4} , {1,3,7,8} ,...{4,5,7,8} ).

We say that an element s of S can be "covered" by K "tiles" of T if there exist K tiles in T such that the union of their sets of terms contains the terms of s as a subset. For example, subsequence {1,2,3} is possible to cover with 2 tiles of length 2 ({1,2} and {3,4}), while subsequnce {1,3,5} is not possible to "cover" with 2 "tiles" of length 2, but is possible to cover with 2 "tiles" of length 3 ({1,2,3} and {4,5,6}).

Let C be the subset of elements of S that can be covered by K tiles of T.

Find the cardinality of C given M, L_T, L_S, K.

Any ideas would be appreciated how to tackle this problem.

Comment: What if M is not divisible by T? Do we have the last tile which is shorter then?

Comment: This might be better suited for math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Assume `M` is divisible by `T`, so that we have an integer number of tiles covering all elements of the initial set (otherwise the statement is currently unclear).

First, let us count `F (P)`: it will be almost the number of subsequences of length `L_S` which can be covered by no more than `P` tiles, but not exactly that.
Formally, `F (P) = choose (M/T, P) * choose (P*T, L_S)`.
We start by choosing exactly `P` covering tiles: the number of ways is `choose (M/T, P)`.
When the tiles are fixed, we have exactly `P * T` distinct elements available, and there are `choose (P*T, L_S)` ways to choose a subsequence.

Well, this approach has a flaw.
Note that, when we chose a tile but did not use its elements at all, we in fact counted some subsequences more than once.
For example, if we fixed three tiles numbered 2, 6 and 7, but used only 2 and 7, we counted the same subsequences again and again when we fixed three tiles numbered 2, 7 and whatever.

The problem described above can be countered by a variation of the inclusion-exclusion principle.
Indeed, for a subsequence which uses only `Q` tiles out of `P` selected tiles, it is counted `choose (M-Q, P-Q)` times instead of only once: `Q` of `P` choices are fixed, but the other ones are arbitrary.

Define `G (P)` as the number of subsequences of length `L_S` which can be covered by exactly `P` tiles.
Then, `F (P)` is `sum for Q from 0 to P` of the products `G (Q) * choose (M-Q, P-Q)`.
Working from `P = 0` upwards, we can calculate all the values of `G` by calculating the values of `F`.
For example, we get `G (2)` from knowing `F (2)`, `G (0)` and `G (1)`, and also the equation connecting `F (2)` with `G (0)`, `G (1)` and `G (2)`.

After that, the answer is simply `sum for P from 0 to K` of the values `G (P)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but regarding the T, it is the set of tiles of length L_T, e.g. if M=8 and L_T=3 then T={{1,2,3}; {2,3,4}; {3,4,5}; {4,5,6}; {5,6,7}; {6,7,8}}, so |T|=6 and it is not necessary to be divisor for M. In this case if k=1 and L_S=3, i.e. I need to find the number of subsequences of length 3 (set C), which is possible to cover with any one tile, then |C|=6(out of 56 possible) and C==T.
From the other side if k=2, i.e., ... cover using any two tiles from T, then |C|=46(out of 56 possible). For example, {1,4,8} is not possible to cover with 2 tiles.

Comment: @Grigor: Ouch! With this comment, you just turned the problem into a very different one! Note how you mention that the tiles _do not overlap_ in the question and present an _example L_T = 3, subsequences are {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},..._ which is **not** {1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5},{4,5,6}... as you are stating now. Please decide which problem you want to solve, and write a rigorous statement.

Comment: Yeah I see it, sorry for misleading description. Actually the tiles can overlap. I have edited my initial post correspondingly.